# Django: How to do something in init state of ModelAdmin

Tags: django

Currently I have something like this:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib import admin
import requests

API_SERVER= 'https://someapiserver.com'

class Member(models.Model):
    nodeid = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    authorized = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
    assigned_ip = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='USE IP')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nodeid', 'name','authorized', 'assigned_ip', 'from_ip')

    def from_ip(self, obj):
        try :
            r = requests.get(f'{API_SERVER}/peer/{obj.nodeid}')
            srcData = r.json()
            srcIP = srcData['from_ip']
            return srcIP
        except Exception as e :
            return 'Unknown'
```

I realize that with above methode, I need to make a http call for each custom field ('from_ip').

Acttualy, the API_SERVER can give me list of all peer in single call by just use

```
    r = requests.get(f'{API_SERVER}/peer')
```

My question is : How to define a 'custom variable' inside this modelAdmin in init state, so that I can change my custom field definition like

```
    def from_ip(self, obj):
        try :
            srcData = [p for p in self.peers if p['id'] == obj.nodeid][0]
            srcIP = srcData['from_ip']
            return srcIP
        except Exception as e :
            return 'Unknown'
```

Sincerely
-bino-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
import requests

API_SERVER = 'https://someapiserver.com'

class Member(models.Model):
    nodeid = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    authorized = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
    assigned_ip = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='USE IP')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nodeid', 'name', 'authorized', 'assigned_ip', 'from_ip')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MemberAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.peers = self.get_peers()

    def get_peers(self):
        try:
            r = requests.get(f'{API_SERVER}/peer')
            return r.json()
        except Exception as e:
            return []

    def from_ip(self, obj):
        try:
            srcData = next((p for p in self.peers if p['id'] == obj.nodeid), None)
            if srcData:
                srcIP = srcData['from_ip']
                return srcIP
            else:
                return 'Unknown'
        except Exception as e:
            return 'Unknown'

# Register the MemberAdmin class for your Member model
admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)
```